# Include statement in php file

Tags: php, security, include

I have a php file (php1.php). Within that php file i have the following line:

```
     include('php/PROTECT/login.php')
```

However when i load the page i get the following error:

```
    Warning: include(php/login.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

it just totally ignores the /PROTECT/ section?

Does anyone have any ideas why this is and how i can resolve the issue?

My file structure is as follows: (php1.php is within /php and login.php is within /php/PROTECT

Comment: probably PHP tries to find the 'PROTECT' constant. You should use quotes as Evert has showed.

Comment: I have used quotes.. just mis-typed when entering it here. 

Not sure who -1'd but wtf is all i can say

Comment: ok don't be disappointed. Just make sure you avoid typos next time. are u including other files in the login.php file ? you should check those includes too.

Comment: No, the only include is within the php1.php file. login.php has no includes

Comment: So if a semicolon is not missing after the include statement then i have to say that you are looking for a file that does not exist at the location that you specify. make sure that the file is there or specify the correct path to the file.

Comment: Have you made sure that the the read permissions are set correctly? The user the server runs under must have read access to the file.

Comment: the folder PROTECT has a .htaccess file which conatins the statement: 'deny from all' which i was advised in one of my other stackoverflow questions that would mean that a brwoser could not view it but my php files would be able to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make absolutely sure that that's the include call that's throwing the error. Make sure that no other code, in php1.php or in any file it has included or required tries to include php/login.php.

Answer (score 2):

It should look like:

```
include('php/PROTECT/login.php');
```

Comment: Sorry dont know why it appeared like that my statement is actually like include ('php/PROTECTED/login.php'); Still doesnt work though

Answer (score 0):

If `php1.php` is within `/php/` (which I understand it to be), then you will need to use the following:

```
include('PROTECT/login.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Includes in includes can be a bit messy, but if you concatenate with **DIR** it is easier. **DIR** is always path to the file it self, if you use **DIR** you can always use the relative path. Like this:

include **DIR** . "/PROTECT/login.php";

Answer (score -1):

As you can see by the error message:

```
Warning: include(php/login.php)
```

"`PROTECT`" is excluded from the path, probably for being in all caps.

Change the directory to all lowercase ("`protect`" or similar) and see if you get the same error.